# How to write an array list of array list of an object to parcel?

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parcel

I have this `ArrayList`

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<MyCustomObject>>schedule;
```

So each element of this array is another array list of my custom object

How would I go about writing this to parcel?

**This is my initial approach but wondering if there is a clean and shorter way.**

**Writing to parcel**

```
if(schedule != null){
        dest.writeInt(schedule.size());
        for (ArrayList<MyCustomObject> schedules : schedule) {
            dest.writeTypedList(schedules);
        }
    }
```

**Reading from parcel**

```
int sizeOfSchedule = in.readInt();
        schedule = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfSchedule; i++){
            schedule.add(in.createTypedArrayList(MyCustomObject.CREATOR));
        }
```

**UPDATED 1 : Tested the above and it works**

Comment: So what's the endpoint/product that you want to reach?

Comment: @DarkV1 What i posted works but look how much code it is. I want to see if there is shorter way, maybe it exists in the framework already but I could not find any examples of writing an array of array of objects to parcel